# お店の営業開始終了時刻をデータベースへ格納したいのですが、データ型は何が良い？

Tags: mysql, データベース設計

**お店の営業開始終了時刻をMySQLへ格納したいのですが、データ型は何が良いでしょうか？**
・とりあえずvarchar指定したのですが、時間なのでtime型へ変更した方が良い？
・time型へ変更するメリットはあるでしょうか？
※time型を一度も使用したことがないのですが、どういう時に使用するデータ型なのでしょうか？

---

**時刻をデータベースへ格納する時、「:」も含めるのでしょうか？**
・それとも外す？

```
10：00
```

もしくは

```
1000
```

---

**24時を過ぎた時刻の格納について**
・例えば26時閉店の場合、02:00でデータ格納した方が良いのでしょうか？

・当初は26:00をそのまま格納しようと思ったのですが、フォームを下記にしたら24:00以降に指定できないことに気が付いたので
・加工すれば格納可能だと思うのですが、一般的にプログラムの世界では24:00以降でデータを持たない(00:00～24:00間へ変換して保存する)のでしょうか？

```
<input type="time">
```

・それぞれメリットデメリット等あれば教えてください

Comment: 現状`varchar`で保存されているということは、主な用途はUI等への表示でしょうか？また、24時間営業の場合はどのような値が入ることを想定されますか？(null ? or 0:00-24:00 ? or 想定する必要なし?)

Comment: 今のままだとケースバイケースとしか言えないので、要件をもう少し絞れませんか。書かれていない前提条件や制約条件が隠れているように思われます。

Comment: 主な用途はUI等への表示です。24時間営業の場合にどのような値を入れるかについては、現在検討中です

Comment: ＞今のままだとケースバイケースとしか言えない。要件は現在検討中です。逆に言えば、これぐらいの内容なら何れでも良い(時刻は必ずしもtimeでなくても良い)のかな、と思いました

Answer (score 7, accepted):

人により回答が異なるかもしれませんが…

私なら0:00からの経過時間で格納すると思います。
INT型(ミリ秒)、TIME型のどちらでもよいと思います。

TIME型は、O/Rマッパーを使用していれば、プログラミング言語に対応したTIME型のオブジェクトとして取得できるかと思います。

主な利点は以下の通りです。

- データがUIの表示フォーマットに依存しない

  - 時間の表記はアプリ側で自由に変更可能
  - つまり多言語化対応などがしやすい
- 各種言語の日時型と親和性が高い

  - 特定の日の0:00に加算すれば、その日の開店時間 / 閉店時間になる
  - 現在時刻から閉店までの時間を算出したりなど
- SQL上で比較可能

  - ある店舗より閉店時間の遅い店舗の抽出など
- 差を取れば何時間営業なのか取得できる

  - SQL上では[`TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)で計算できます

---

> 24時を過ぎた時刻の格納について

DB設計ではなくUIなので要件によるかと思います。

閉店時間に開店時間より小さい時間が入力されていた場合、閉店時間に24時間加算するとかでしょうか？
(開店時間 = 閉店時間の場合は24時間営業)

UIで開店時間と閉店時間が変更されたタイミングで`(n時間営業)`みたいな表示を隣に出せば混乱もなさそうな気はします。
(23時～翌22時のような時間を設定できてしまうことやこのUIの良し悪しなど、要件によります)

いずれにしてもDBへ26時のデータが格納されていたとしても、表示時には26時とも2時とも表示することはできます。

---

> ※time型を一度も使用したことがないのですが、どういう時に使用するデータ型なのでしょうか？

単純に時間(`HHH:MM:SS`)を格納するためのデータ型です。

11.3.2 TIME 型
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/time.html

> MySQL では、TIME 値の取り出しと表示は 'HH:MM:SS' 形式 (時間の部分の値が大きい場合は 'HHH:MM:SS' 形式) で行われます。TIME 値の範囲は、'-838:59:59' から '838:59:59' です。TIME 型は、時間 (24 時間以下にする必要があります) を表すだけでなく、経過時間や、2 つのイベント間の時間 (24 時間よりも非常に長くなる場合も、負になる場合もあります) を表すこともできるので、時間の部分は非常に大きくなる可能性があります。

Comment: TIME型にしようと思いました。現在の要件は「UI等への表示」だけなので何れを選択しても問題ない(と思う)のですが、将来的に要件が増加した場合、後でデータ型を変更するのは大変だと思い質問しました。回答を読んで時刻については素直にTIME型にしておいた方が、拡張する必要性が生じた場合、一番対応しやすそうに感じました。24時間以上については表示上の問題なので、0～24で格納して、表示する際処理しようと思います